# Kafka General A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka

I try to start kafka in docker with this docker compose file in two different hosts:

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    environment: 
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
    environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL://:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://:9092
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false
        KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: true
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: broker.keystore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: broker.truststore.jks
        KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass
        KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
        KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SSL
        KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: " "
        KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
    volumes:
        - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
```

At one host everything is fine, but at another I get error

```
"Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings."
```

I use different certificates. Only difference, as I see, it's different signature algorithm - at host where all good it's SHA-512 with RSA, and where I have an error it's SHA-384 with ECDSA and different key size - 2048 bits vs 4096. But as I find in Google, kafka will work with both of them. And I haven't possibility to change certificates - I need to find solution with this certs.

What can be cause of this error?

Comment: `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` needs a hostname, by the way, such as `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: localhost:9092`. But your two hosts with this compose file aren't talking to each other, if that's what you're trying to do... Also unrelated, but Confluent 5.5.7 is out of support, I think

Comment: No, with `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL://:9092` setting zookeeper and broker can connect to each other. With this setting broker return container id as a hostname. But of course I can't connect to broker outside docker in this case) At this example I just removed ip address that I using.

Comment: Sure, I meant that you have a port forward, so I assumed you were trying to connect outside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Problem was in certificate that I used - it didn't contain in the key usage field "Client Authentication". I found it when I tried to run latest version of kafka and this version gave me error about key usage field.